# Big Query landing page figures not consistent with Google Analytics interface

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery to report on Google Analytics data. I'm trying to recreate landing page data using BigQuery.

The following query reports 18% fewer sessions than in the Google Analytics interface:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitID,
  h.page.pagePath AS LandingPage
FROM
  `project-name.dataset.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE 
  hitNumber = 1
AND h.type = 'PAGE'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170331' AND '20170331'
ORDER BY fullVisitorId DESC
```

Where am I going wrong with my approach? Why can't I get to within a small margin of the number in the GA interface's reported figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple reasons :

1.Big Query for equivalent landing page:

```
SELECT
  LandingPage,
  COUNT(sessionId) AS Sessions,
  100 * SUM(totals.bounces)/COUNT(sessionId) AS BounceRate,
  AVG(totals.pageviews) AS AvgPageviews,
  SUM(totals.timeOnSite)/COUNT(sessionId) AS AvgTimeOnSite,
from(
  SELECT
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId,STRING(visitId)) AS sessionID,
    totals.bounces,
    totals.pageviews,
    totals.timeOnSite,
    hits.page.pagePath AS landingPage
  FROM (
    SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId,
      hits.page.pagePath,
      totals.bounces,
      totals.pageviews,
      totals.timeOnSite,
      MIN(hits.hitNumber) WITHIN RECORD AS firstHit,
      hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber
    FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE ([XXXYYYZZZ.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2016-08-01'), TIMESTAMP ('2016-08-31')))
    WHERE
      hits.type = 'PAGE'
      AND hits.page.pagePath'')
  WHERE
    hitNumber = firstHit)
GROUP BY
  LandingPage
ORDER BY
  Sessions DESC,
  LandingPage
```

---

Next :

**Pre-calculated data -- pre-aggregated tables**

These are the precalculated data that Google uses to speed up the UI. Google does not specify when this is done but it can be at any point of the time. These are known as pre-aggregated tables

---

So if you compare the numbers from GA UI to your Big Query output, you will always see a discrepancy. Please go ahead and rely on your big query data .

Comment: Thanks for your response @Tushar. If I understand you correctly my query only looked at hitNumber = 1 which was why it was under reporting by 18%. It needs to consider cases when the first hit isn't labelled as 1, hence the min function. Also, even then the GA interface sacrifices some accuracy in order to scale. Running your query above suggests the inaccuracy could be as high as 6% based on my site's data. Does that sound about right? No I've got to figure out how to re-write your query in standard SQL, probably for another question though!

Comment: @goose I work as an analyst myself closely with google. The accepted rate of the discrepancy is 5-10%. But I won't stop you writing and checking by yourself. Let me know if you have any concerns. May be I can help :)

Comment: Thanks again @Tushar - I wasn't suggesting it wasn't, I just wanted to check I'd understood correctly. That's useful to know.

Comment: Oki you wrote No after question mark, It was meant to be now ;) Sorry for confusion :D

Comment: Ah, my bad. Yes mis-type. D'oh!

Comment: are you able to clarify whether the margin of error that you refer to above that GA interface has from its processing is separate to or realted to the sampling feature? i.e does the 5-10% tolerance apply even if the interface shows as being based on 100% of sessions? As I continue to write queries this question keeps popping up in my mind.

Comment: @goose yes that's correct! even you process with 100% of sessions, there still of 5-10% of error margin ;) Classic Google

Comment: Thanks again Tushar

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing by simply adding the below to your select statement:

`,(SELECT page.pagePath FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE hitnumber = (SELECT MIN(hitnumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type = 'PAGE')) landingpage`

I can get a 1 to 1 match with the GA UI on my end when I run something like below, which is a bit more concise than the original answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   a.landingpage
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(a.sessionId)) sessions
  ,SUM(a.bounces) bounces
  ,AVG(a.avg_pages) avg_pages
  ,(SUM(tos)/COUNT(DISTINCT(a.sessionId)))/60 session_duration
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) sessionId
      ,(SELECT page.pagePath FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE hitnumber = (SELECT MIN(hitnumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type = 'PAGE')) landingpage
      ,totals.bounces bounces
      ,totals.timeonsite tos
      ,(SELECT COUNT(hitnumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type = 'PAGE') avg_pages
    FROM `tablename_*`
      WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20180801'
       AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= '20180808'
        AND totals.visits = 1   
) a
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

another way here! you can get the same number :

```
    SELECT 
LandingPage,
COUNT(DISTINCT(sessionID)) AS sessions
FROM(
SELECT    
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId,CAST(visitId AS STRING)) AS sessionID,
    FIRST_VALUE(hits.page.pagePath) OVER (PARTITION BY  CONCAT(fullVisitorId,CAST(visitId AS STRING)) ORDER BY hits.hitNumber ASC ) AS LandingPage
FROM
    `xxxxxxxx1.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    AND hits.type ='PAGE'
GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitId, sessionID,hits.page.pagePath,hits.hitNumber
)
GROUP BY LandingPage
ORDER BY sessions DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hit.isEntrance field in the schema that can be used for this purpose.
The example below would show you yesterday's landing pages:

```
#standardSQL
select
  date,
  hits.page.pagePath as landingPage,
  sum(totals.visits) as visits,
  sum(totals.bounces) as bounces,
  sum(totals.transactions) as transactions
from
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`,
  unnest(hits) as hits
where
  (_table_suffix
    between format_date("%Y%m%d", date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day))
    and format_date("%Y%m%d", date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)))
  and hits.isEntrance = True
  and totals.visits = 1 #avoid counting midnight-split sessions
group by
  1, 2
order by 3 desc
```

There is still one source of discrepancy though, which comes from the sessions without a landing page (if you check in GA in the landing pages report, there will sometimes be a *(not set)* value.

In order to include those as well, you can do:

```
with
landing_pages_set as (
  select
    concat(cast(fullVisitorId as string), cast(visitId as string), cast(date as string)) as fullVisitId,
    hits.page.pagePath as virtualPagePath
  from
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`,
    unnest(hits) as hits
  where
    (_table_suffix
      between format_date("%Y%m%d", date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day))
      and format_date("%Y%m%d", date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)))
    and totals.visits = 1 #avoid counting midnight-split sessions
    and hits.isEntrance = TRUE
  group by 1, 2
),

landing_pages_not_set as (
  select
    concat(cast(fullVisitorId as string), cast(visitId as string), cast(date as string)) as fullVisitId,
    date,
    "(not set)" as virtualPagePath,
    count(distinct concat(cast(fullVisitorId as string), cast(visitId as string), cast(date as string))) as visits,
    sum(totals.bounces) as bounces,
    sum(totals.transactions) as transactions
  from
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
  where
    (_table_suffix
      between format_date("%Y%m%d", date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day))
      and format_date("%Y%m%d", date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)))
    and totals.visits = 1 #avoid counting midnight-split sessions
  group by 1, 2, 3
),

landing_pages as (
  select
    l.fullVisitId as fullVisitId,
    date,
    coalesce(r.virtualPagePath, l.virtualPagePath) as virtualPagePath,
    visits,
    bounces,
    transactions
  from
    landing_pages_not_set l left join landing_pages_set r on l.fullVisitId = r.fullVisitId
)

select virtualPagePath, sum(visits) from landing_pages group by 1 order by 2 desc
```